# Default SelectedItem for a WPF ComboBox inside a DataTemplate used in an ItemsControl not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

How can I get a WPF `ComboBox` that is within a `DataTemplate` within an `ItemsControl` element to have, and always have, a default `SelectedItem`, all while sticking strictly to the MVVM pattern?

My goal is to define a list of "form fields" that then are translated, via templates, into actual form fields (i.e. - `TextBox`, `ComboBox`, `DatePicker`, etc.). The list of fields is 100% dynamic and fields can be added and removed (by the user) at any time.

The pseudo-implementation is:

```
MainWindow
    -> Sets FormViewModel as DataContext
FormViewModel (View Model)
    -> Populated the `Fields` Property
Form (View)
    -> Has an `ItemsControl` element with the `ItemsSource` bound to FormViewModel's `Fields` Property
    -> `ItemsControl` element uses an `ItemTemplateSelector` to select correct template based on current field's type**
FormField
    -> Class that has a `DisplayName`, `Value`, and list of `Operators` (=, <, >, >=, <=, etc.)
Operator
    -> Class that has an `Id` and `Label` (i.e.: Id = "<=", Label = "Less Than or Equal To")
DataTemplate
    -> A `DataTemplate` element for each field type* that creates a form field with a label, and a `ComboBox` with the field's available Operators
    *** The `Operators` ComboBox is where the issue occurs ***
```

** The actual field's "type" and the implementation contained therein is not included in this question as it's not relevant to the display issue.

Here are the primary classes required to generate the form, based on the pseudo-implementation above:

FormViewModel.cs

```
public class FormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    protected ObservableCollection<FormField> _fields;
    public ObservableCollection<FormField> Fields {
        get { return _fields; }
        set { _fields = value; _onPropertyChanged("Fields"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void _onPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public FormViewModel() {
        // create a sample field that has a list of operators
        Fields = new ObservableCollection<FormField>() {
            new FormField() {
                DisplayName = "Field1",
                Value = "Default Value",
                Operators = new ObservableCollection<Operator>() {
                    new Operator() { Id = "=", Label = "Equals" },
                    new Operator() { Id = "<", Label = "Less Than" },
                    new Operator() { Id = ">", Label = "Greater Than" }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Form.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="DataTemplates.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource fieldTemplateSelector}">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Form.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Form : UserControl {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Fields", typeof(ObservableCollection<FormField>), typeof(Form));

    public ObservableCollection<FormField> Fields {
        get { return ((ObservableCollection<FormField>)GetValue(FieldsProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(FieldsProperty, ((ObservableCollection<FormField>)value)); }
    }

    public Form() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

FieldTemplateSelector.cs

```
public class FieldTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector {
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container) {
        FrameworkElement element = (container as FrameworkElement);
        if ((element != null) && (item != null) && (item is FormField)) {
            return (element.FindResource("defaultFieldTemplate") as DataTemplate);
        }
        return DefaultTemplate;
    }
}
```

DataTemplates.xaml

```
<local:FieldTemplateSelector x:Key="fieldTemplateSelector" />
<DataTemplate x:Key="defaultFieldTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Operators}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Label" SelectedValuePath="Id"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOperator, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

FormField.cs

```
public class FormField : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    protected ObservableCollection<Operator> _operators;
    public ObservableCollection<Operator> Operators {
        get { return _operators; }
        set {
            _operators = value;
            _onPropertyChanged("Operators");
        }
    }

    protected Operator _selectedOperator;
    public Operator SelectedOperator {
        get { return _selectedOperator; }
        set { _selectedOperator = value; _onPropertyChanged("SelectedOperator"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void _onPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Operator.cs

```
public class Operator {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

The form is properly generated; All "form fields" in the `Fields` list are created as `TextBox` elements with their name's displayed as labels, and they each have a `ComboBox` full of operators. However, the `ComboBox` doesn't have an item selected by default.

My initial step to fix the issue was to set `SelectedIndex=0` on the `ComboBox`; this didn't work. After trial and error, I opted to use a `DataTrigger` such as the following:

```
<ComboBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Operators}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Label" SelectedValuePath="Id"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOperator, Mode=TwoWay}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- select the first item by default (if no other is selected) -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}"  Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

The trigger I added will check if the current `SelectedItem` is `null` and, if so, set the `SelectedIndex` to 0. This works! When I run the application, each `ComboBox` has an item selected by default! But wait, there's more:
If an item is then removed from the `Fields` list and at any time added back, the `ComboBox` has no item selected again. Basicaly, what's happening is, when the field is created for the first time, the data-trigger selects the first item in the operators list and sets that as the field's `SelectedItem`. When the field is removed and then added back, `SelectedItem` is no longer `null` so the original DataTrigger doesn't work. Oddly enough, even though there is clearly a binding for the SelectedItem property, the currently-selected item is not being selected.

Summarized: When a `ComboBox` is used within a DataTemplate, the `SelectedItem` for the `ComboBox` is not using its bound property as a default value.

What I've tried:

1. DataTrigger when `SelectedItem` is null to select the first item in the list.
   Result: Correctly selects the item when the field is created; Loses the item when the field is removed from the display and then added back.
2. Same as 1, plus a DataTrigger for when `SelectedItem` is not null to re-select the first item in the list.
   Result: Same as #1 Result + Correctly selects the first item in the list when the field is removed from the display and then added back; If the entire `Fields` list itself is recreated using already-created `FormField` items, the selected item is empty again. Also, it would be nice to pre-select the previously selected operator (not a requirement though).
3. Used `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`, with - and without - DataTriggers (as in #1 and #2).
   Result: Did not successfully select default items in either case, almost as if the `SelectedIndex` was being read before the `ItemsSource`.
4. Used a DataTrigger to check the `Items.Count` property; if it was greater-than-zero, set the `SelectedItem` to the first element in the list.
   Result: Did not successfully select an item.
5. Same as 4, but using `SelectedIndex` instead of `SelectedItem`.
   Result: Same as #1 Result
6. Used `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` with both `True` and `False` values.
   Result: Nothing selected.
7. Re-ordered the XAML properties to place `SelectedItem` (and `SelectedIndex`, when used) to be before `ItemsSource`. This was done for every test as I've read online that it helps.
   Result: Doesn't help.
8. Tried different types of collections for the `Operators` property. I've used `List`, `IEnumerable`, `ICollectionView`, and am currently using `ObservableCollection`.
   Result: All provided the same output, except `IEnumerable` - it lost the value after the field was removed/re-added.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a CollectionView together with a IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true". Have you tried putting SelectedItem property before ItemsSource. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156705/wpf-combobox-selecteditem  ... also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815447/combo-box-loses-selection-after-collection-changes

Comment: @colinsmith Yes to both. Regarding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"`  - see #6 in my "have tried" list. Though not specified (but being added), I have also tried re-ordering the XAML attributes by placing `SelectedItem` (and `SelectedIndex`) before `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Just to clarify, you've tried a CollectionViewSource these are 2 good articles on how they work -> http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=387  ?  and http://drwpf.com/blog/category/collections/   and this http://shevaspace.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/when-selectorissynchronizedwithcurrenti.html

Comment: @colinsmith Though they are decent articles, I don't see how they help my situation (I could be missing your point though). I've been going off of the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317860/should-i-bind-to-icollectionview-or-observablecollection regarding the different types of collections - which seems to be a good summary/argument.

Comment: My idea is that you need an implementation of ICollectionView which monitors a change of the underlying collection, so that when  the CurrentItem is equal to an item that is getting removed from the collection, you reset the CurrentItem to something else, and do a Refresh perhaps....i.e. you are managing the currency. The bindings in your combox are then synchronized with the currentitem/collectionviewsource. Excuse if a poor explanation or wrong track.

Comment: Damn.  This is the kind of place where a minimal prototype that repros would be helpful.  Also, MVVM != no codebehind.  UI logic still belongs there.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the hint regarding the codebehind; I was stuck trying to handle everything through XAML and the hack-list kept growing longer and longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I restructured my application and the above issue is no longer present, I have also figured out a solution to solving it!

The steps:

1. Taking a hint from a comment by Will, I updated the `Form`'s codebehind to add a [`PropertyMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597502.aspx) callback to the `FieldsProperty`.
2. The callback from #1 iterates through the entire list of fields and uses [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) to invoke a Delegate-Action on an [`Input`-priority level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) that will set the current field's `SelectedOperator` to the first operator in the field's `Operators` list.

   - Without using `.BeginInvoke()` or any other lower priority, the update would attempt to access the field before it was GUI-generated and would fail.
3. Removed the `DataTriggers` from the `Operators` `ComboBox` in the `DataTemplate` (now, it is the same as the first code-example for `DataTemplates.xaml` in my question).

New, working code (updates only):

Form.cs

```
...
public static readonly DependencyProperty FieldsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Fields", typeof(ObservableCollection<FormField>), typeof(Form), new PropertyMetadata(_fieldsListUpdated));
...
// PropertyMetaData-callback for when the FieldsProperty is updated
protected static void _fieldsListUpdated(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) {
    foreach (FormField field in ((Form)sender).Fields) {
        // check to see if the current field has valid operators
        if ((field.Operators != null) && (field.Operators.Count > 0)) {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input, (Action)(() => {
                // set the current field's SelectedOperator to the first in the list
                field.SelectedOperator = field.Operators[0];
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

The slight caveat to the above is that the `SelectedOperator` will always be set to the first in the list. For me, this isn't an issue - but I could see a case where the "last-selected-operator" would want to be re-selected.

After debugging, when the `Field` is added back to the list of `Fields`, it still retains the previous `SelectedItem` value - and then the `ComboBox`'s `SelectedIndex` is immediately set to `-1`. Preventing this in the setter for `FormField.SelectedOperator` (and by trying `SelectedItem`/`SelectedIndex`) doesn't help.

Instead, creating a second "placeholder" Property in `FormField` named `LastOperator` and setting it to the `SelectedOperator` when the setter is passed `null`, and then updating the `field.Operator =` line in `Form.cs` seems to work:

FormField.cs

```
...
public Operator SelectedOperator {
    get { return _selectedOperator; }
    set {
        if (value == null) LastOperator = _selectedOperator;
        _selectedOperator = value; _onPropertyChanged("SelectedOperator");
    }
}

public Operator LastOperator { get; set; }
```

Form.cs

```
...
field.SelectedOperator = ((field.LastOperator != null) ? field.LastOperator : field.Operators[0]);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

FormField.cs

```
protected ObservableCollection<Operator> _operators;
public ObservableCollection<Operator> Operators {
    get { return _operators; }
    set {
        _operators = value;
        _onPropertyChanged("Operators");
    }
}

private QuestionOption _selectedItem;
    public QuestionOption SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem != value)
            {
                if (SelectedIndex == -1)
                    SelectedIndex = Operators.IndexOf(value);
                _selectedItem = value;
                _onPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _selectedIndex = -1;
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return _selectedIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedIndex != value)
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                _onPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }
    }
```

DataTemplate.xaml

```
<ComboBox Width="Auto" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Operators}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Label" SelectedValuePath="Id">
```

As for ensuring that changes to the Fields fire the PropertyChanged event try the following to force the event to fire:

```
// Set the changes to the modifiedFormField placeholder
ObservableCollection<FormField> modifiedFormField;
this.Fields = new ObservableCollection<FormField>(modifiedFormField);
```

I experienced a similar issue whilst working on an MVVM Silverlight 5 Application and did something similar to this to get the binding working. The concepts should be interchangeable with WPF. Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `SelectedIndex` is in my list of "what I've tried" - and isn't successful. I've also tried the idea of binding both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` and it didn't work either. Additionally, I have no issues with the `PropertyChanged` event firing and I've confirmed they are properly dispatched in every instance they're supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Using ComboBoxes with databound SelectedItem, inside DataTemplate is tricky.. 
I resolved this by: instead of using SelectedItem, (TwoWay) bind only **SelectedValue** (to your custom type property - SelectedOperator) and set **DisplayMemberPath** (but NOT SelectedValuePath - to have the whole custom type instance as a value)